# Integration using Stokes' theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d, stokes-theorem, curl

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out.
Given a surface $S$:
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \newline
z = y^2
\end{cases}
Let $C$ be the edge of $S$. $C$ is oriented so that the projection of $C$ on the $xy$-plane runs counter-clockwise. Calculate:
\begin{equation}
\oint_{C}y^2dx + xy^2 dy+ xzdz
\end{equation}

1. Directly
2. Using Stokes's theorem

I've tried to make a sketch of the area with the orientation:

[image]

[image]

I've at least gotten
\begin{equation}
\vec{F} = y^2 \vec{i} + xy^2 \vec{j} + xz \vec{k}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
curlF = -z\vec{j} + (y^2-2y)\vec{k}
\end{equation}

For calculating the integral directly I've tried a parametrization:
\begin{cases}
x = r\cos(t) \newline
y = r\sin(t) \newline
z = y^2 = r^2\sin^2(t)
\end{cases}
with $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.
This gave me:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r^2\sin^2(t) + r^2\cos(t)\sin^2(t) + r^3\cos(t)\sin^2(t) dtdr = \frac{1}{3} \pi
\end{equation}

But now for $\iint_{R} curlF \cdot N dS$ I can't figure out how to proceed. I can't seem to figure out what $N$ is and what integration bounds I need to use. The examples in my book and my lecture  aren't all that similar and I don't see how to apply those to this situation.
If someone could give me a hint on how to proceed I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Your parametrization of $C$ does not make sense, it should be is a line.. If you let $r$ tkae any value in [0,1] your are parametrising the surface, not the border.
$$ x = \cos t,\quad y = \sin t, \quad z = \sin^2 t$$ 
Using the parametrization the line integral becomes a 1d integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards the other side of Stokes' theorem, we may consider the surface
$$S=\{(x,y,y^2): x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$$
oriented upwards.
[image]

A parametrization of $S$ is given by
$$\mathbf{r}(x,y)=(x,y,y^2) \; \text{with $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$} \implies 
\mathbf{r}_x\times \mathbf{r}_y= (0,-2y,1).$$
Therefore
$$\iint_S \text{curl}(\mathbf{F})\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\iint_{\{x^2+y^2\leq 1\}}
(0,-z,y^2-2y)\cdot (0,-2y,1) \,dx dy=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
which is equal (please fill the details) to the direct computation made by PierreCarre.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the direct calculation, a possible parametrization would be
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \cos t\\y = \sin t\\ z = \sin^2t
\end{cases}
$$

The line integral can be computed as
$$
\int_C y^2 dx + xy^2dy+xz dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} (\sin^2 t \cdot (-\sin t)+\cos t \sin^2 t \cdot \cos t + \cos t \sin^2 t \cdot 2 \cos t \sin t) dt = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$